# FreeTypeFontGenerator for GWT

Tags: gwt, libgdx, freetype

I'm using Libgdx to write an Android and HTML5 app. I have found out that FreeTypeFontGenerator doesn't work for a GWT application and truetype is deprecated. What shall I use if I want to use fonts in a GWT application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `BitmapFont` just like you do in any LibGDX application, it is the standard mechanism to support fonts in LibGDX. FreeTypeFontGenerator is an *extension* that doesn't work for GWT because it features native code. If you need to *pre*-generate some new font files of different sizes and types you can use [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) or my favorite [BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/).

Comment: I'm trying with BMFont, it works fine with standard font like Arial, but I want to use and custom font. The font works fine if you install it to windows, it also looks great in BMFont. But when i try to import it with libgdx, I just got random stuff. am i messing up the settings or is it something else?

Comment: Look at the resulting fnt and png file. Do they make sense? png has glyph renderings and the fnt correctly specifies the location and size of each letter?

Comment: The png make sense, so i think the something get wrong with the fnt-file. maybe something wrong with the offset. How do I know what settings i shall have for a specific font?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some better way, but if you can't find any, you can prerender the font in a few sizes with the Hiero tool built into the `gdx-tools` project, and choose the most fitting one at runtime. Hiero generates a .png and a file describing the characters in that image which you can simply load, e.g.:

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font/font"+sizeNum+".fnt"));
```

Comment: Is this working in HTML5? TTF is important at online games.

Comment: Well, this is NOT ttf, but if you render enough versions of the bitmap font, it should be good enough. As far as I know, it works (no personal experience though)

Comment: You are right, there must be a way to achieve this. It is unfortunate font support is not advanced as Flash in LibGDX.